# Unclear Swift coding

Tags: swift, function, dictionary

```
var occurences: [Int : Int] = [:]  
for number in numbers {  
  if var value = occurences[number] {  
    occurences[number] = ++value  
  } else {  
    occurences[number] = 1
  }  
}
```

I understand the first 2 lines that it declares an empty dictionary and I have an array of numbers to iterate in a for-in loop, but can someone explain the 4th and 5th line, please. I just don't get how it declares which one is the key and which one is the value. Thank you so much, stucking here for like 2 days.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34258789/2303865

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
if var value = occurences[number]
```

means that it checks to see if `occurences` has some value stored for key `number` and then in next line

```
 occurences[number] = ++value
```

it increments the value by using `++` and then saves that to the `occurences` dict.

Comment: The ++value is going away come swift 3, and should be replaced with value + 1 (and thus also let instead of var). I know, not your code, but worth mentioning as the ++ part is horribly intuitive in this code example!

Comment: The same applies to `if var`

Comment: @TofuBeer and in that case you will have to do `value += 1` and the (in the next line) `occurences[number] = value`

Comment: @VladimirNul occurences[number] = value + 1 there is no need for ++ or += at all

Comment: @TofuBeer You are right, in this case it isn't. I was thinking in a case where value is set outside the loop.

Comment: @Shamas S how do you know that it is asking to check in the key of the dict instead of value? Is it because it is if var VALUE? Can you just name it value cuz it is called value in the dictionary... I kinda get your point but still a a little confused. And one more question, may you just simply explain reduce function, like what does it do.

Comment: @DavidZou I think you misunderstood. It's getting the value for they key which in this case is named as `number`.  The result is stored in `value`. If the `value` is not zero, `value` is incremented, and then saved back in the dictionary named `occurences`