# How can I get all unique elements from a collection in Swift

Tags: swift

If I got this array:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
```

How can I get:

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/removing-duplicate-elements-from-an-array) will hold the duplicate's value, but I want to remove that value as well.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/41272542/2976878

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to filter only the numbers that appear 1 single time you can use the good old `NSCountedSet`

```
let nums = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: nums)
let uniques = nums.filter { countedSet.count(for: $0) == 1 }

print(uniques) // [2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that you need to import Foundation to use NSCountedSet. If you need a pure Swift solution to find the unique elements of a collection you can extend it constraining the elements to the Equatable protocol and check if you can *not* find the element index again checking if index(of: element) == nil using the index(after:) the element index as the startIndex of the collection subsequence:

Edit/update: **Swift 4.2.1**

Note that extending RangeReplacebleCollection it will cover StringProtocol types `String`and `Substring` as well:

Constraining the element to `Equatable`

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1**

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element: Equatable {
    var uniqueElements: Self {
        filter { self[index(after: firstIndex(of: $0)!)...].firstIndex(of: $0) == nil }
    }
    mutating func removeAllNonUniqueElements() { self = uniqueElements }
}
```

If you don't need to keep the collection original order, you can take advantage of the new Dictionary initializer but this would need constrain the elements to `Hashable`:

```
init<S>(grouping values: S, by keyForValue: (S.Element) throws -> Dictionary<Key, Value>.Key) rethrows where Value == [S.Element], S : Sequence
```

and keep the keys where the values equals to 1

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element: Hashable {
    var uniqueElementsSet: Set<Element> {
       Set(Dictionary(grouping: self, by: { $0 }).compactMap{ $1.count == 1 ? $0 : nil })
    }
}
```

---

Playground Testing

```
let numbers = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
numbers.uniqueElements    // [4, 2, 3]
```

---

If you need to keep the collection's order you can get the element frequency as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258731/count-the-occurences-a-particular-integer-has-in-an-array/34258789#34258789) and filter the unique elements:

```
extension Sequence where Element: Hashable {
    var frequency: [Element: Int] { reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 } }
}
```

---

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element: Hashable {
    var uniqueElements:  Self { filter { frequency[$0] == 1 } }
    mutating func removeAllNonUniqueElements() { self = uniqueElements }
}
```

---

Playground testing

```
let numbers = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
numbers.uniqueElements   // [2, 3, 4]

var string = "0011123455"
string.uniqueElements       // "234"
string.uniqueElementsSet    // {"4", "3", "2"}
print(string)  // "0011123455\n"

 // mutating the string
string.removeAllNonUniqueElements()
print(string)  // 234
```

Comment: Thanks I will use that extension!